# How to install Tamil language in Ubuntu touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

How should I install the Tamil language on Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 5? I can't even install just the ttf-Tamil-fonts through the terminal.

Any solution that would let me read Tamil on the web browser would be appreciated.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: do you want to change the OS operational language into tamil, else just want to enter tamil text ?

Comment: Both or any one please I cant able to read Tamil in web also in Ubuntu touch

Answer (score 1):

I had faced same issue and I got it resolved. Steps are below,
First run :

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

and then run

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-tamil-fonts.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy to change languages on Ubuntu Touch using the following steps,

1. Open the **System Settings** app and press the **Language and Text** setting.

[image]

2. Then you can set the display language and the keyboard language to Tamil. I would expect this to automatically install the necessary fonts required. If you are still unable to read Tamil in the browser, please proceed to file a bug.

[image]

Comment: In the display language their is no Tamil language option displayed and Tamil keboard to select please help